# Creating RSS feeds for individual nodes

Tags: feeds

Is there any way to have rss feeds for individual nodes, taxonomies and so on.Right now we have rss feed for the entire website.

for example :
I'd like to access a node feed through http://www.musite.com/node/1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) you can add a *Feed* display, with a path that contains a with a wildcard component (e.g. **/rss/%/feed**), & *Content: Nid* for a contextual filter. This will create a path that will have an RSS feed for each nid (e.g. http://www.example.com/rss/1/feed. http://www.example.com/rss/2/feed, etc.).

Comment: Any webservice model?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Yup I got it,
By using REST service, it is possible.